# Get Latest will give an error if file is Not downloaded

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When Source Control Explorer shows that a file is `Not Downloaded`, selecting Get Latest Version will result in the following:

[image]

I don't remember this happening in the past. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Hi Old Geezer, any update on this issue.Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error or situation may occur when using "Get Latest Version" after someone else has just added a new item to source control.

For example, it seems to be triggered by multiple people working on the same solution at the same time. So if you check stuff in, then the other user gets this message when doing a "Get Latest". It appears Visual studio is detecting the files that were checked in by the other user and then pulling them in the background but not updating the local workspace data, so when you do a Get Latest, the files already exist, but it gets confused as to the source control status and throw this because it's confused.

One solution for this issue is closing your Visual Studio and [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Then open the Visual Studio and get latest for this file again.

Another way is directly  removing the work space and create a new one then tfs will prompt you to download everything again. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181386(v=vs.100).aspx  This should do the trick.

Comment: My problem is certainly not the case where another person had updated the file **while** I was downloading it. It happens all the time whenever a file has the `Latest` column showing `Not downloaded`. I rebooted my PC, but it is still happening for *all* new files. I don't want to take the drastic action of clearing the cache at this time. It is too risky, and I will rather live with the pesky incorrect error messages.

Comment: @OldGeezer If so, instead of clearing cache, you could also try to create a new workspace, delete your old one(back up files first). Then try to get latest for all files. Which may do the trick.